# I want to create a folder in multiple folders available

Tags: vbscript, directory

I want to create a folder in multiple folders available (by VBScript)

Example:

I have multiple folders: abc, xyz, ijk ... etc.

- I want to create a folder as "ABC" in all folders abc, xyz, tyu, ijk..etc
- Then move all files "jpg" in each folder abc, xyz, tyu, ijk .. into the folder "ABC" of each folder just created
- Check each folder and see if the folder "ABC" or not, empty or not

---

```
strFolder = "/"   '<== This place how to automatically create a folder "ABC"
                  '    in the directory available

SET objFSO = CREATEOBJECT("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Move file jpg    '<== I do not get it

IF objFSO.FolderExists(strFolder) = FALSE THEN
  objFSO.CreateFolder strFolder
  wscript.echo "Folder Created"
ELSE
  wscript.echo "Folder already exists"
END IF
```

Comment: Your question isn't a question. :) Is there a specific issue you're having trouble overcoming?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me ! I've edited, can you help me?

Comment: How do you determine the folders in which you want to create the new subfolder? Where are "all jpg files" located before you move them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question which was written as an answer...

```
Dim fso, shl, curdir, folder, file, newfoldername, newfolderpath
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set shl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
curdir = shl.CurrentDirectory
newfoldername  = "big"

For Each folder In fso.GetFolder(curdir).Subfolders
    newfolderpath = fso.BuildPath(folder.Path, newfoldername)
    If Not fso.FolderExists(newfolderpath) Then
        fso.CreateFolder newfolderpath
        WScript.Echo newfolderpath & " created"
    Else
        WScript.Echo newfolderpath & " already exists"
    End If
    For Each file In folder.Files
        MoveFile file.Path, newfolderpath
    Next
Next

Sub MoveFile(source, destination)
    On Error Resume Next
    fso.CopyFile source, destination & "\", True ' true = overwrite
    If Err Then
        WScript.Echo "Error copying " & source & " to " & destination & ": " & Err.Description
        WScript.Quit
    Else
        fso.DeleteFile source, True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

The `MoveFile` sub acts as a regular move, i.e. copies file and then deletes source if successful. Better than using the built-in fso.MoveFile function as that one doesn't handle overwriting existing files.

In summary... on each subfolder in the current directory, see if subfolder\big exists. If so then echo text, else create folder and echo text. Then for each file in that subfolder, move it to the subfolder\big folder, overwriting existing files, and delete the source file if the copy was successful. You could add stuff to check the extension before moving (to target only certain file types), or exit sub if the file already exists (to not overwrite existing files).

Comment: First of all, thank you for the reply, great algorithm! 
I'm sorry very much, I do not know how to finish this toppic ?