# I want to move the file from the directory (2) in the subdirectory (1) to a subdirectory (1) and delete the folder (2) by VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I want to move the file from the directory (2) in the subdirectory (1) (after deleting all files in subfolders (1)) to a subdirectory (1) and delete the folder (2)

For example:
 I have a folder in disk:

```
D:/ABC/123/"big" + (with a.jpg;b.jpg;c.jpg..ect)/1.jpg,2.jpg;3.jpg ..ect..
D:/ABC/456/"big" + (with d.jpg;e.jpg;f.jpg..ect)/4.jpg;5.jpg;6.jpg ..ect..
D:/ABC/789/"big" + (with g.jpg;h.jpg;k.jpg..ect)/5.jpg;6.jpg;7.jpg ..ect..
```

I want delete (a.jpg;b.jpg;c.jpg..ect) in "123" then move (1.jpg,2.jpg;3.jpg ..ect..) in subfolders "big" to "123" then delete "big"

loop all for subfolders in "ABC"

I try :

```
Dim fso, shl, curdir, folder, file, newfoldername, newfolderpath,subb
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set shl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
curdir = shl.CurrentDirectory
newfoldername  = "big"

Sub curdir(Folder)
For Each folder In fso.GetFolder(curdir).SubFolders
        For Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
            set subb = fso.GetFolder(curdir).Subfolders
                For Each file In folder.Files
                MoveFile file.Path, Folder.SubFolders
                Next
        Next
Next
End Sub

Sub MoveFile(source, destination)
    On Error Resume Next
    fso.CopyFile source & "\", destination, True ' true = overwrite
    If Err Then
        WScript.Echo "Error copying " & source & " to " & destination & ": " & Err.Description
        WScript.Quit
    Else
        fso.DeleteFile source, True
        WScript.Echo "Delete"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

I'm a beginner, help me :)

Comment: I wrote most of the [code you posted here for another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258551/i-want-to-create-a-folder-in-multiple-folders-available), did it answer that question? If so, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Really, I am very poor in spoken english, Thank you for reminding me! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each objFolder In objFSO.GetFolder("D:\ABC").SubFolders

    ' Delete all of the files in this folder...
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        objFile.Delete
    Next

    ' Now move all of the files from the "big" subfolder to this folder...
    For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(objFolder.Path & "\big").Files
        objFSO.MoveFile objFile.Path, objFolder.Path & "\" & objFile.Name
    Next

    ' Finally, delete the "big" subfolder...
    objFSO.DeleteFolder objFolder.Path & "\big"

Next
```

Comment: Thank you for guiding me, I would have done! How close this topic, thanks again!

Comment: No problem. You can accept this as the answer to close this question. Good luck.